# Merge a git branch, while excluding changes to some directory

Tags: git

I would like to merge changes from a branch B to my branch A, in such a way that the merge excludes any changes to a given directory. The problem here is that I have some commits which span changes over multiple directories, one of which needs to be excluded.

Is something like that possible, for example, with history rewriting?

To clarify, my directory structure is:

```
root/x
root/y
root/z
```

some of the commits affect all three directories. Now, I would like to merge in such a way that I have changes in the history to both `y` and `z`, but not to `x`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can merge the other branch without committing it, then resetting the state of the directory:

```
git merge --no-commit <branch>
git reset root/x
git commit
```

better yet to split your commits as mentioned by [@useless in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014150/merge-a-git-branch-while-excluding-changes-to-some-directory/7014563#7014563)

Comment: Thanks. This last step is something I would like to avoid. Rebase seems like a nice thing to try, but I have over 100 commits...

Comment: Avoiding atomic commits in git is like avoiding water in the shower. You're free to try it, but it's just not how the thing was meant to be used, and you're going to work a LOT harder.

Comment: True :) What I had in mind is something complementary to `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter`. However, there is no such thing, and I don't even know how should I script one...

Comment: @nikola: you could use `--index-filter` with filter-branch if you really want to rewrite the history of your branch

Comment: If I split commits, how do I merge them independently? I mean, when merging, all commits up to the selected commit being merged are taken. I'm not really sure to understand this way. The `--no-commit` way is clear instead.

Comment: @empo: There's no splitting of commits happening here. What do you mean?

Comment: I'm referring to "better yet to split your commits as mentioned..."

Answer (score 3):

If your changes are all still local, the easiest way is by [splitting your commits](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_splitting_commits) into genuinely orthogonal changes you can merge independently.

---

Dead link repair: try [this link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-rebase) instead (or just see your local manpage for *git rebase*), and search down for *Splitting Commits*.

Comment: If I split commits, how do I merge them independently? I mean, when merging, all commits up to the selected commit being merged are taken. I'm not really sure to understand this way. The `--no-commit` way is clear instead.